# Sub-process returned an error code when apt-get install package

Tags: apt, software-installation, packagekit, numa

```
sudo apt-get install  numactl

E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success '/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

[image]
How to fix it?

Comment: That’s from PackageKit. What happens if you run `/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update` yourself (as root)?

Comment: No error info ,just output `()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt remove appstream
```

Just remove it .